# F# FS0556 and FS0554 Property Syntax error

Tags: f#

Why am I getting the error with the follow property declarations?  I'm trying make a concrete class from an abstract class with a property override to implement the property.

```
module Test =

    type VD(id : int) =
        member this.id = id

    [<AbstractClass>]
    type V<'V> when 'V :> VD (v : 'V option) =

        abstract member Preds : V<'V> list with get

    type PV<'D> when 'D :> VD (v : 'D option) =
        inherit V<'D> (v)
        member _.Preds<'D> : Vertex<'D> list
            with get() : V<'D> list = Utils.impossible<V<'D> list>()
            and set(_) : unit = Utils.impossible<unit>()
;;
              with get() : V<'D> list = Utils.impossible<V<'D> list>()
  -----------------^^^^^

stdin(71,18): error FS0556: Type annotations on property getters and setters must be given after the 'get()' or 'set(v)', e.g. 'with get() : string = ...'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the type annotation on the `member` line. It shouldn't be there. Annotations are only allowed on getters and setters (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/properties)). And same goes for the generic parameter by the way.

Try this:

```
        member _.Preds
            with get() : V<'D> list = Utils.impossible<V<'D> list>()
            and set(_) : unit = Utils.impossible<unit>()
```

But this is still (probably) not what you wanted. From the rest of the code I infer that what you probably wanted was to override the abstract member from `V`, right?

If so, you should use `override` instead of `member`:

```
        override _.Preds
```

But even *that* won't be enough, because the `Preds` abstract member only has a `get`, but no `set`, so you can't override it with both (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/properties#abstract-properties)). If you really need a `set`, you'd have to make it a separate method.

So, taking all of the above into account, this is how it should look:

```
        override _.Preds
            with get() : V<'D> list = Utils.impossible<V<'D> list>()

        member _.setPreds(_) : unit = Utils.impossible<unit>()
```

And since you only have a `get`, but no `set`, you might as well just use shorthand syntax:

```
        override _.Preds : V<'D> list = Utils.impossible<V<'D> list>()
        member _.setPreds(_) : unit = Utils.impossible<unit>()
```